# WIX - Run custom action on installation cancellation

Tags: wix, wix3, custom-action

I'm wirintg an installer using WIX and I need to execute a custom action when a user press the "cancel" button.

I've created a custom action but I don't seem to find where to use that action.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: can u tell me under which tag u are adding this line `<Custom Action="MyAction" OnExit="cancel">1</Custom>` I mean under `<InstallExecuteSequence>`or  `<InstallUISequence>` or some other Tag?

Comment: #Rasa It's been awhile since I've made this change. perhaps #VitalyVal can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<Custom Action="MyAction" OnExit="cancel">1</Custom>
```

Answer (score 0):

OnExit="cancel" may fail if standard WIX UI is used (WIX assigns another action to "cancel" event). Action execution could be assigned to finish button in this case

```
<Publish Dialog="UserExit" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="MyAction">NOT Installed</Publish>
```